# ¿Como puedo contar el tiempo de la sesion desde que inicia hasta que termina? en PHP

Tags: php

Lo que debo hacer es un control de parqueos, pero la cuota de los clientes que lleguen, debe calcularse segun el tiempo, desde que ellos inicien la sesion en el parqueo, hasta la hora de que ellos quieran salir y pagar... necesito esa funcion, pero no se como hacerlo, me estaba basando en este fragmento de codigo para hacerlo:

```
<?php

        //Obtenemos el tiempo actual.
        $time = time();
        $tiempo_actual = date('Y-m-d  H:i:s', $time);

        $strStart = $tiempo_actual;
        //Tiempo de expira.
        $strEnd   = '2100-12-12 00:00';    

        //Convierte la cadena en una variable de fecha.
        $dteStart = new DateTime($strStart);
        $dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd);

        //Calculamos la diferencia 
        $dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);    

        //Salida de data.
        print $dteDiff->format("%H:%I:%S");

    ?>
```

Pero no he logrado nada aun... Gracias de Antemano por responder...

Comment: ¿Cómo has gestionado la persistencia? ¿Almacenas en algún sitio la hora de llegada de cada usuario?

Comment: si, o bueno creo que funciona asi no? trataba de hacer que con el session_start() o algo asi obtener el tiempo de la sesion.... la verdad es que no tengo ni la menor idea de como hacer eso...

Comment: ¿Qué es parqueo? ¿Aparcamiento? ¿Inician sesión en una aplicación web al llegar? ¿Y si cierran la sesión antes de pagar? Si guardas la hora de llegada en una base de datos, no necesitas guardar nada en variables de sesión, ¿no?